# Custom Order, Invoice, and Shipping Starting Numbers

Tags: orders, shipping, invoice, custom

What's the safest approach to change the next starting numbers for order, invoice, and shipment on a live site?

Comment: Best option https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-order-number.html

Answer (score 7):

If I want to continue using Magento's default increment type and just want to change the next increment number, this is what I use.

**Be sure to only use increment numbers that are larger then ones already used!**

```
SET @next_increment='310000000';

SELECT @entity_types:=GROUP_CONCAT(`entity_type_id`) FROM `eav_entity_type`
    WHERE `entity_type_code` IN ('order', 'invoice', 'shipment');

SELECT @new_last_increment:=GREATEST((@next_increment -1), 
    (SELECT MAX(`increment_last_id`) FROM `eav_entity_store`
     WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`entity_type_id`, @entity_types)));

UPDATE `eav_entity_store` SET `increment_last_id`=@new_last_increment
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`entity_type_id`, @entity_types);
```

This SQL should take care of not accidentially setting an increment ID that was used already.
If a larger increment then `next_increment` already was used, it simply sets the last increment number for all three entity types to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the safety lever but I'm doing it by modifying values in DB directly:

```
    UPDATE `eav_entity_store` s
INNER JOIN `eav_entity_type` t ON t.`entity_type_id` = s.`entity_type_id`
       SET s.`increment_last_id` = 'your_increment_here'
     WHERE t.entity_type_code = "order";
```

Replace entity type code with "invoice" or "shipping" to do the same for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use custom number ranges or formats for increment IDs instead of the default Magento increments, you can also assign a custom increment model.

For example:

```
class My_Shop_Model_Entity_Increment_Erp
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Abstract
{
    public function getNextId()
    {
        $last = $this->getLastId();
        $entity = $this->getEntityTypeId();
        $store = $this->getStoreId()
        $next = Mage::helper('my_shop/api')->getNextIncrementFromErp($last, $entity, $store);

        // If you want to apply pad char and length, otherwise simply return $next
        return $this->format($next);
    }
}
```

Then, update the increment model for the entities in a setup script:

```
$installer = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup',   'core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->updateEntityType('order',    'increment_model', 'my_shop/entity_increment_erp');
$installer->updateEntityType('invoice',  'increment_model', 'my_shop/entity_increment_erp');
$installer->updateEntityType('shipment', 'increment_model', 'my_shop/entity_increment_erp');
$installer->endSetup();
```

**Be sure not to return increment IDs that already where used previously!**

Answer (score 2):

The best [safest for magento] way to change the order number is to change the next order numbers and not the previous ones.
This can be done with a simple database query.
These are the ones I used in my site and it is working without any problem for almost a year now.

Order:

```
    UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='XXXXXXXXXX'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';
```

Invoice:

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='XXXXXXXXXX'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='invoice';
```

Shipment:

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='XXXXXXXXXX'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='shipment';
```

These queries will change the next increment ids for your magento store.
NOTE: Replace X with the next id that you want.

Accept a answer if it works.

Comment: Copied from here I guess http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/

Comment: yes and the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Order Increment ID and Prefix

Change your Order Increment ID on All Stores

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='XXXXXXXXXX'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';

UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='XXXXXXXXXX'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='invoice';
```