# changeing order number sequence

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

By default way of magento, while creating a order order number starts with `10000..` I would like to change the order number starting sequence.

I studied from other answer [Custom Order, Invoice, and Shipping Starting Numbers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25712/custom-order-invoice-and-shipping-starting-numbers) I understood that we can modify table `eav_entity_store`

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-order-number.html Simple solution

Comment: @GauravJain this question was asked long ago when I was a fresher. Anyway, the solution is much simpler, no need to invest $25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Change the column increment_last_id in the eav_entity_store table. You can also change the incremental prefix in that table. Make sure you change the  value for the correct store id.

Comment: can we use dd/mm/yy as increment_prefix, actually i want to add the orderdate in front of order ids